# The Stalled in the network takes a long time

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-devtools

This is Timing tab
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD36K.png)
This is network list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKflb.png)
Every request is form disk catch, but Stalled time is so long, I wonder why

My computer performance should be good, too
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbltQ.png)

Look for answers online and the Chrome developer site, but no reason was found